# Change ListViewItem background color by using an index specified by a property

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger

I'm new to WPF, I have a property that defines an `int` which is the index of the element to change the background color within the `ListView` but is changing the background color of all the `ListViewItem`, here my code:

```
<ListView AlternationCount="2147483647" x:Name="listView1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="295" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="380" Padding="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="1" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" SelectionMode="Single" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemContexMenuKey}"/>

                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Value="True">
                                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IndexConverter}">
                                            <Binding Path="AlternationIndex" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}"/>
                                            <Binding Path="TargetIndex" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}"/>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFF7171"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>

                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
   </ListView>
```

Here the IndexConverter

```
public class IndexConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int index = (int)values[0];
        int targetIndex = (int)values[1];

        Console.WriteLine($"Index: {index}, TargetIndex: {targetIndex}");
        return index == targetIndex;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In the `IndexConverter.Convert` the local variable index is the `AlternationIndex` and always is returning 0.

I don't get why this behaviour, when using trigger it works corretly, but you can't bind using Trigger.

```
<Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFF7171"/>
</Trigger>
```

Comment: `ItemsControl.AlternationIndex` is a so-called attached property. It is NOT a property of an ItemsControl itself, but rather a property attached to some item by the ItemsControl (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview). Thus, your AlternationIndex binding is incorrect. Try binding against the ListViewItem itself, using `"(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)"` as binding path. (The parentheses might or might not be necessary; i don't recall.)

Comment: @elgozo ``<Binding Path="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListViewItem}"/>`` I tried that but I get an error, " Cannot find source for binding with reference..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @elgonzo, `ItemsControl.AlternationIndex` is an [attached property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview) that you should bind to like this:

```
<Binding Path="(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)" 
         RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
```

Note the parentheses around the path.

Comment: I tried that but I get ``System.Windows.Data Warning: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=(0); DataItem=null; target element is 'ListViewItem' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')``

Comment: In the converter I'm getting an ``InvalidCastException``

Comment: @FreddxL.: See my edit. Since you are in the `ItemContainerStyle`, you should specify `{RelativeSource Self}` as the source.

Comment: Thanks, now is working but only changing the color of the ListViewItem in the position 0, the cause could be the converter, I'll check.